# Classic ASP.Net show current MQTT Values with HTML5?

Tags: html, asp.net, mqtt

i want show permant the current state of a MQTT Broker Topic (Value) with HTML5? on an classic ASP.Net Webpage. Is this possible? 
How refresh i the page and show the value from the MQTT Broker as light bulb?

Answer (score 0):

You don't!

Just add the Paho JavaScript client and subscribe to the topic in the page and update it live.

You will need to make sure your broker supports MQTT over Websockets, but pretty much all do these days.